# User top questions list somehow has an invalid question ID

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, top-questions

I ran across [this user](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/315/cramertv) who has a fairly prolific SE profile. But I noticed something odd in their list

[image: Missing link]

The question link is as such

```
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/-2147481790/34047#34047
```

A negative question ID? Wait, the first number seems out of place entirely! I went looking and found it's really [this Law.SE answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/34047/29211), so the ID is correct at the end. A rather interesting bug in their profile page.

Comment: Probably because I edited the question, I'm known to break things. </jk> The question *has* been migrated: https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/34046/revisions which might have influenced this bug.

Comment: @Glorfindel Would explain a lot

Comment: @AdamLear This question has been marked as a duplicate, of one of my questions that was already tagged [tag:status-review] long before the recent escalation process began. Does this mean my request has been escalated?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Well... in combination with the fact that apparently we do have an ongoing bug (and not just an old "bad data" problem like I thought), let's say... yes. :)